# Alert Message in Java popping up too fast

Tags: java, scenebuilder

Screenshot:
[image: PICTURE HERE]
I'm trying to implement an alert using scenebuilder, it's working. The only problem is it doesn't wait for the user to start typing anything in the field before displaying the error message. As soon as I click on add part it displays the Error message before even changing scenes. It does change scenes after I exit click 'ok' on the alert. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private boolean validateInput(){
        try{
           double dPrice = 1.00;
           dPrice = Double.parseDouble(addPartPrice.getText());

       } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe){
           AlertMessage.errorPart(3, addPartPrice);
           return false;
       }[enter image description here][1]
        try{
           int iStock = Integer.parseInt(addPartInventory.getText());
       } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe){
           return false;
       }
        try{
           int iMin = Integer.parseInt(addPartMin.getText());
       } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe){
           return false;
       }
        try{
           int iMax = Integer.parseInt(addPartMax.getText());
       } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe){
           return false;
       }
        if(!partIsoutSourcedFromCompany){
        try{
           int iID = Integer.parseInt(addPartSource.getText());
       } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe){
           return false;
       }
        }
        return addPartName.getText() != null &&
                addPartSource.getText() != null &&
                Integer.parseInt(addPartMin.getText()) >= 0 &&
                Integer.parseInt(addPartMin.getText()) <= Integer.parseInt(addPartInventory.getText()) &&
                Integer.parseInt(addPartInventory.getText()) <= Integer.parseInt(addPartMax.getText()) &&
                Double.parseDouble(addPartPrice.getText()) >= 0;
    }
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I added a picture at the very top

Comment: i am sorry,  i didn't see. it is possible to load the code to github

Comment: It has the link and blue lettering saying PICTURE HERE:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCUHp.png

Comment: i would like to look the code, it is possible to upload to github

Comment: https://github.com/stoicprogrammer1/sw1

Comment: Edit your question, and include the code which calls `validateInput()`.  A github link is not sufficient;  if the account ever goes away, your question will be useless to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

you have to bind your validatInput method to the add-button/function. So the code execution (that means validateInput) is pending until the user clicks on the add-Button.